# Searching in multiple sorted array and its complexity

Tags: algorithm, search, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

Given 3 sorted array. Find 3 elements, one from each array such that a+b=c. Can it be done less than O(n^3) time complexity? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in O(N^2 * logN) complexity by iterating through 2 of the arrays for a and b and binary searching for c in the third array.

Another method would be O(N^2) by inserting the elements of one of the arrays into a hash, iterate for a and b in the other two arrays and looking if c = (a + b) exists in the hash.

Comment: For method 2, is there any efficient way to solve it since it is given that all 3 arrays are already sorted?

Comment: You can't generate the (a,b) pairs better than O(N^2) ... The searching in the hash is O(1)

Answer (score 4):

Call the three arrays `A`, `B` and `C`, and the elements `a`, `b` and `c`.

While looping through the first two arrays, since if `a` is fixed, `b` can only increase, `c` also can only increase.

So you don't have to loop through `C` every time you have a pair of `a` and `b`; just loop through `C` while looping though `B` will do.

Now Suppose all three arrays have length O(N), the time complexity is O(N^2), since for each value in `A`, you need to go through all of `B` and all of `C`, the number which is O(N).